# Detect right button - ANDROID PhoneGap

Tags: android, button, cordova, addeventlistener

How can I detect the right button?? (used to show shared methods)

For example, in my Xperia NEO I have 3 buttons, the first button is used like "back button", and In the source code can detect it with:

**`document.addEventListener("backbutton", FUNCTION(), true);`**

But now I need to detect the right button, anybody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to detect menu button:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#menubutton

Comment: But this button exists for all android devices?

THANKS! ;)